# Кастомный error yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как переопределить **error** метод? в конфиге у меня так

```
'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
```

в контроллере вот так

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionError()
{
    exit('asd');
}
```

Но все равно сюда он не стучит...В чем дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При установке по умолчанию, шаблона `basic`, в конфигурации приложения можно увидеть регистрацию следующего компонента:

```
...

'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],

...
```

Что говорит о том, что мы будем использовать в нашем приложении класс [`yii\web\ErrorHandler`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-errorhandler.html), который наследуется от [`yii\base\ErrorHandler`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-errorhandler.html); у данного класса есть свойство [`errorAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-errorhandler.html#$errorAction-detail), название которого говорит само за себя — то есть экшен ошибок; иными словами, экшен, который будет обрабатывать ошибки ...

В конфигурации мы видим, что экшеном для обработки ошибок назначен экшен `site/error`. Хорошо — идём в контроллер `site` ...

В контроллере `site` мы видим, что у него переопределён метод [`actions()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-controllers.md#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-) (*карта действий*), в котором и указан наш экшен `error`.

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Стало быть, так как метод `actions()` [выполняется до любого экшена](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-controllers.md#%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-) (карта же, ну ... — нужна для того, чтобы определить маршрут), то ваш метод `actionError()` не вызовется, так как экшен уже найден и им является [`yii\web\ErrorAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-erroraction.html):

```
'error' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
],
```

который рендит вид в папке `@app/views/site/error.php` ...

Здесь, думаю, уже понятно, что можно просто изменить файл `@app/views/site/error.php` как вам нужно и вы получите нужный вид ...

В этом файле можно использовать следующие переменные:

> $name: the error name
>
> $message: the error message
>
> $exception: the exception being handled

Подробнее в документации: [`yii\web\ErrorAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-erroraction.html).

Comment: Просто дело в том что я хочу в контролле отловить 403 ошибку и уже редиректить его куда не надо. я так понимаю что во вьюхе это делать плхая практика.

Comment: @Анатолий, а что значит «редериктить куда надо» — вы должны сообщить пользователю, что доступ запрещён (403), чтобы он понимал почему не может получить ответ от сервера. Но если так сильно нужно, то ловить следует, по-моему, в контроллере, он же контролирует процесс запрос-ответ.

Comment: Ну к примеру если неавторизованный пользователь пытается зайти в админку то я бы хотел не показывать что доступ запрещен а сразу редиректить его на страницу с авторизацией

Comment: @Анатолий, если вы клоните к тому, чтобы не дать узнать злоумышленнику структуру сайта (в частности, админки), то я, например (хотя я не злоумышленник :D), увидев бы редирект, сразу бы понял, что там что-то важное, раз меня перенаправили, а вот если бы вы дали 404, то здесь уже 50/50. А в общем, не думаю, что всё это того стоит — пускай стучаться ...

Comment: С точки зрения безопасности,думаю что Вы правы. Но админам было бы удобнее если он не авторизован, то его перекидывало бы на страницу с авторизацией)